# Fastest factorial implementation with 64-bit result in assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly, factorial

This is not homework, just something I though of. So, straight computing factorial is not exactly fast; memoization can help, but if the result is to fit into 32 or 64 bits, then the factorial only can work for inputs `0` through `12` and `20` respectively. So ... we might as well use a lookup table:

```
n   n!
0   1       
1   1       
2   2       
3   6       
4   24      
5   120     
6   720     
7   5040        
8   40320       
9   362880      
10  3628800     
11  39916800        
12  479001600       
13  6227020800  2^32=   4294967296
14  87178291200     
15  1.30767E+12     
16  2.09228E+13     
17  3.55687E+14     
18  6.40237E+15     
19  1.21645E+17     
20  2.4329E+18      
        2^64=   1.84467E+19
```

So, suppose I want to have an inline C++ factorial function which uses inline assembly, with a 32 bit or 64 bit unsigned integer expected as a result. If the input is either negative or large enough to cause overflow, the output should be 0. How can this be done in assembly such that it consumes the least amount of cycles? This code will run on a 64-bit Intel/AMD architecture. If feasible, I am interested in improving the worst case scenario, so `20!` should not take a lot longer to compute than `0!` - hopefully there is a binary search approach. Hopefully there is a clever trick for doing `if (n == 0 || n == 1) { return 1; }`. Also, if the output needs to be 32 bit, then I think assembly instructions can contain both code and data in them. My assembly knowledge is weak. Please let me know if the question does not make a whole lot of sense.

Being able to use the function in C++ would be nice - makes it a more realistic problem. If, for instance, calling a function is expensive, then trying to save 1-2 clock cycles in the body of the assembly will not help much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have cleverly built a lookup table in assembly.  Just in case you're rusty on your assembly,
The routine expects the parameter to be in the `ecx` register. I verify that it is in range then read the lookup table's values into the `eax` and `edx` registers.  If the value is out of range, I just xor the `eax` and `edx` registers with themselves (this forces them to 0).  Unfortunately, since it's an assembly routine the compiler will be unable to inline the code.  But, I'm sure the few cycles I saved by writing my awesome assembly routine will more than make up for any gain by inlining.

```
factorial:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    cmpl    $20, %ecx
    ja  .TOOBIG
    movl    CSWTCH.1(,%ecx,8), %eax
    movl    CSWTCH.1+4(,%ecx,8), %edx
.TOOBIG:

LOOKUP_TABLE:
    .section    .rodata
    .align 32
    .type   CSWTCH.1, @object
    .size   CSWTCH.1, 168
CSWTCH.1:
    .long   1
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   0
    .long   2
    .long   0
    .long   6
    .long   0
    .long   24
    .long   0
    .long   120
    .long   0
    .long   720
    .long   0
    .long   5040
    .long   0
    .long   40320
    .long   0
    .long   362880
    .long   0
    .long   3628800
    .long   0
    .long   39916800
    .long   0
    .long   479001600
    .long   0
    .long   1932053504
    .long   1
    .long   1278945280
    .long   20
    .long   2004310016
    .long   304
    .long   2004189184
    .long   4871
    .long   -288522240
    .long   82814
    .long   -898433024
    .long   1490668
    .long   109641728
    .long   28322707
    .long   -2102132736
    .long   566454140
```

The lookup table is difficult to maintain, so I've included the script I used to build it

```
static constexpr uint64_t const_factorial(uint32_t i) {
    return (i==0)? 1: (i * const_factorial(i-1));
}

uint64_t factorial(uint32_t i) {
    switch(i) {
        case 0: return const_factorial(0);
        case 1: return const_factorial(1);
        case 2: return const_factorial(2);
        case 3: return const_factorial(3);
        case 4: return const_factorial(4);
        case 5: return const_factorial(5);
        case 6: return const_factorial(6);
        case 7: return const_factorial(7);
        case 8: return const_factorial(8);
        case 9: return const_factorial(9);
        case 10: return const_factorial(10);
        case 11: return const_factorial(11);
        case 12: return const_factorial(12);
        case 13: return const_factorial(13);
        case 14: return const_factorial(14);
        case 15: return const_factorial(15);
        case 16: return const_factorial(16);
        case 17: return const_factorial(17);
        case 18: return const_factorial(18);
        case 19: return const_factorial(19);
        case 20: return const_factorial(20);
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Just in case you missed it in my poor attempt at humor.  The C++ compiler is more than capable at correctly optimizing your code.  As you can see I didn't need to do anything fancy with lookup tables, binary search trees, or hashes.  Just a simple `switch` statement and the compiler did the rest.

Comment: I don't think it's quite obvious that you're using templates to force the compiler to compute the lookup table at compile time.

Comment: @Gabe: the compiler would generate the same code if I placed literal values directly in the switch rather than compute them at compile time.  I didn't want to get into the details of meta programming.  I figure if Hamish is uncomfortable with them he can just compute the factorials by hand.

Comment: Caspin: Yes; I said is wasn't obvious because after you posted your code, somebody (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207094/fastest-factorial-implementation-with-64-bit-result-in-assembly/3208703#3208703) wrote an answer that says "You could probably use templates to build the array too." Either he didn't see your answer, or he saw it and didn't realize what you were doing.

Comment: I stripped the function call stuff from the assembly, it doesn't manipulate the stack either.  If I were a bit more ambitious, I would embed the assembly in as `asm()` statement, then `ret` wouldn't make sense.  As it is it gets the point across, just use C++ and let the optimizer write the assembly for you.

Comment: Saw this surface again. I swapped out the meta-programming for `constexpr`, because it's cooler (probably easier to read as well, but I did it because it's cooler).

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while since I flexed my assembly muscles so I'll just offer some general advice.

Since you know in advance exactly how many and what size all the items will be, just make a contiguous array of values (either hard-coded or pre-calculated). After validating the input to the function (< 0 or > 12/20), you can then use a simple offset addressing to retrieve the appropriate value. This will work in O(1) time.

Comment: Wait ... so, if I wanted to output a 256-bit result, which works for input `0` through `57`, then the approach should be similar, right? Just jump to the offset multiplied by 4.

Comment: @Hamish: Yes, that's right. Though I'd define a structure 256 bits long and have pointer arithmetic take care of the multiplication for you.

Comment: You could also use a std::map<int,SomeBigNumberClassOrType> to `c++`-ify the whole thing

Comment: @ruben, I would love to see an implementation. Non-assembly entries will count. Although ... if map is a hash table, then this is not the fastest approach.

Comment: @Hamish: Re: assembly beating C++, Probably not. Even if you're a bit careless with the C++ code, the compiler will probably emit something extremely similar to what you'd write yourself (if not better).

Comment: @Hamish: A map is a binary search tree. The constant array is the best idea, although realistically, it's unlikely that inline assembler will be faster than C++. It will probably be slower, since the compiler can't optimize it for each specific call site.

Answer (score 1):

Update from the year 2021. Having C++17 at hand.

I guess that there is no faster way than the below. Assembler is not needed.

Because the number of factorials that will fit into an unsigned 64 bit value is very low (21), a **compile time constexpr array** will use mainly only 21*8 = 168 bytes.

**168 bytes**

That number is that low that we can build easily a compile time `constexpr std::array` and stop all further considerations.

Really everything can be done at compile time.

We will first define the default approach for calculation a factorial  as a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long n) noexcept {
    return n == 0ull ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1ull);
}
```

With that, factorials can easily be calculated at  compile time. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all factorials. We use also a `constexpr` and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::integer_sequence` to create a factorials for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { factorial(ManyIndices)... } };
};
```

This function will be fed with an integer sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and return a `std::array<unsigned long long, ...>` with the corresponding factorials.

We know that we can store maximum 21 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the integer sequence 1,2,3,4,...,20,21, like so:

```
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray();
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 21>` with the name Factorial containing all factorials. And if we need the i'th factorial, then we can simply write `Factorial[i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

I do not think that there is a faster way to calculate a factorial.

Please see the complete program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// All the below will be calculated at compile time
// constexpr factorial function
constexpr unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long n) noexcept {
    return n == 0ull ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1ull);
}
// We will automatically build an array of factorials at compile time
// Generate a std::array with n elements 
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { factorial(ManyIndices)... } };
};
// Max index for factorials for an 64bit unsigned value 
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitValue = 21;

// Generate the required number of elements
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
// This is an constexpr array of all factorials numbers
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray();

// All the above was compile time
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Test function
int main() {
    for (size_t i{}; i < MaxIndexFor64BitValue; ++i)
        std::cout << i << '\t' << Factorial[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Developed, compiled and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

Additionally compiled and tested with gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.1

Language: C++17

Comment: Yup, https://godbolt.org/z/5MbhzK shows that clang compiles it to a statically-initialized array.  (If the table was any larger, you might actually *want* it just to be a BSS array computed at run-time, instead of data taking up space in the executable and maybe having to be loaded from disk.  But this isn't much bigger than the asm would be for a constructor loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Who says that your assembly version is going to be any faster than the C++ version anyway.  In fact, who says it will even match in speed?  I'd bet $100 you never even manage to make it as fast as the compiler does.

Comment: Ok ... you could start with a C++ implementation, and then someone will take you up on that $100 bet. I did not down-vote you, btw.

Answer (score 0):

On popular demand, performancewise it's fabled to be a binary search, not a hashtable (std C++ doesn't have that I believe).

```
#include <map>

void main()
{
    std::map<int, BigIntThing> factMap;
    // insert all elements here, probably fancier ways to do this
    factMap.insert( 1 );
    factMap.insert( 1 );
    factMap.insert( 2 );
    // ....
    // to access, say 15!
    BigIntThing factMap[15]; // I think the index is right >_<
}
```

That's it. A `std::map` is  ordered, so if your BigIntThing has a comparison operator all is good. There should be a way to get this `const` and/or `static` and/or `global` to get it compiled in the way you want.

Comment: C++ has a hashmap since TR1, and there's one in Boost.

Comment: Hash tables and binary searches are overkill here. You can just use a flat array, and index into that.

Comment: std::unordered_map is a hash table, but `std::map` usually can't be because it's required to be traversable in order.  Normally it's a red-black tree.  And total overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only working with numbers from 0-19, a hash table or binary tree is overkill. Just create an `unsigned int[20]` and then query the index:

```
const unsigned int FACTORIALS[20] = {1,1,2,6,24,120,etc..};

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int num) {
    if(num >= 0 && num <= 19) {
        return FACTORIALS[num];
    }
    else {
        throw // some sort of exception
    }
}
```

You could probably use templates to build the array too.

Answer (score 0):

### gcc's Answer

...which probably beat's yours, was compiled from:

```
uint64_t answers[] = {
    1ULL,
    1ULL,
    2ULL,
    6ULL,
    24ULL,
    ...
    2432902008176640000ULL,
};

uint64_t factorial(unsigned int i) {
    if(i >= sizeof(answers) / sizeof(*answers))
        return 0;
    else
        return answers[i];
}
```

...and the assembly...

```
factorial:
    cmpl    $20, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    ja  .L3
    movslq  %edi,%eax
    movq    answers(,%rax,8), %rax
.L3:
    rep
    ret
answers:
    .quad 1
    .quad 1
    ...
```

...which seems to be the first 64-bit assembler answer up...

Comment: Why, exactly, do you think that 3 is a better error result than 0?

Comment: 0 is the valid answer of 0!, and thus isn't all that suitable for an error code. 3 is not a valid answer of x! for any x, thus, is available. (1 is 1!, 2 is 2!, 3 is the first such number.)

Comment: Wait, 0! = 1! = 1 ... Google cannot lie http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=0!&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=Cf2Ml3Jk2TLbuFJX6gAS684TmBwAAAKoEBU_Q3db7&fp=bee9b0879ae97c8e

Comment: Wow, good catch, even when I am insisting on being wrong. I apparently have forgotten factorials.

Comment: Edited, hopefully less dain-bramaged now.

Comment: I thought about using 64 bit assembler in my answer, but the 32 bit was much less convoluted.  The 32 bit compiler produced a lookup table where the 64 bit compiler produced a jump table.

Comment: The reason why `0! = 1` is this: `n! = n * (n - 1)!`, so `3! = 3 * 2!`, `2! = 2 * 1!`, and `1! = 1 * 0!`. In other words `0! = 1!/1 = 1`. Now ... they (mathematicians) could have defined base case as: `1! = 1` and claim that `0!` does not exist, but having the value of `0! = 1` also comes very handy in combinatorics, for the reason I once have seen but since forgot. I think it has to do with picking socks out of the box while blindfolded ...

Comment: Hmm, that assembly can be optimized. Add the "error" result as last item in the array and then try 'return answers[MIN(i, sizeof(answers) / sizeof(*answers))];' for the code.
Optimizing compiler will likely create you a conditional move in 64bit mode, eliminating the branch.